# Php webservice that takes JSON via POST and spits back an image

Tags: php, web-services, image, json, image-processing

*(Preamble: This seems like such a typical thing to want to do that I was surprised I didn't immediately find examples and tutorials about it.
So I thought it would be valuable to have as a StackOverflow question.
Pointers to related examples and tutorials will certainly be welcome answers.)*

To make this concrete, the goal is a webservice that accepts data in JSON format via a POST request.
The data is simply an array of single-digit integers, e.g., `[3, 2, 1]`.

On the server are images named 0.png, 1.png, 2.png, etc.
The webservice takes the images corresponding to those specified in the JSON array and composes them into a montage, using the standard ImageMagick command line tool.
For example,

```
montage 3.png 2.png 1.png 321.png
```

creates a new single image, 321.png, composed of 3.png, 2.png, and 1.png, all in a row.

The accepted answer will be in the form of complete PHP code that implements the above.
(I'll write it if no one beats me to it.)

Comment: Is this a question or a job description?

Comment: why should anyone write the complete code for you? stackoverflow is for _helping_ somone who has problems, so try it yourself, show us your code if you got problems and maybe someone can help you to solve it.

Comment: It's a simple artificial problem (but maybe also slightly useful) that I thought would make a nice tutorial.  I'm indeed writing the answer as well.  This is the sort of thing the founders of StackOverflow have encouraged from the beginning.

Comment: "I'll write it if no one beats me to it" --- well, you can start to write your own implementation.

Comment: PS: If you don't have a contribution, no need to comment.  Suppose someone did come along and magnanimously solve my problem for me.  Would that bother you for some reason?  Assuming an answer gets posted here, which I said I'd do myself, surely you must agree that this will be a valuable contribution.  I'm basically using StackOverflow as my own little tech blog.  If I'm misusing StackOverflow please do set me straight.

Comment: @dreeves: if this should have been a tutorial, you should have written that in your question and marked it as community-wiki. i'm not saying you're misusing stackoverflow, but if something should be a wiki, you shoud write it like that and mark it as one.

Comment: Oh, as of just recently there's no way for users to mark their questions community-wiki.  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/392/should-the-community-wiki-police-be-shut-down/7183#7183

Comment: but, as written there, you could have added the "wiki"-tag. also, i'm very shure that yesterday, when i edited one of _my own_ questions, there was a checkbox for "community wiki" as well - but maybe that was just a dream... (PS: the question i'm talking about waas this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3922163/288773)

Comment: @oezi, thanks (and thanks again for hints on the question!) for explaining.  It may have literally been in the last 24 hours that this change happened with marking things community wiki. I don't see the option when I go to edit this question.  Can you point me to the part in that meta.stackoverflow thread about using a wiki tag? I'm not seeing that.

Comment: If this is used in real life, you should probably build in a cache of some kind.

Comment: @dreeves: i think i missunderstood "something should be community wiki then flag it for mod attention" - at first i thought "flag it" is meant as "set the 'wiki'-tag". after reading it again, if i understand it right, the "flag"-option on questions is meant (my english isn't alsways a s good as i want it to be, so sometimes those failures happen). i fact, aber i set the 'wiki'-tag on my question, it was a CW - maybe because a mod changed it in exactly that moment... i can't find the wiki-checkbox on my other question, and my mind is vague about if there realy was one yesterday.

Answer (score 2):

some *hints*, i won't write the complete code for you:

- to get your array back on php-side, there is [json_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.json-decode.php). ise it like this:

  ```
  $images = json_decode($_POST['whatever']);
  ```
- to get the command for montage, do something like this (note: you should valitate all input you get via post, i'm going to leave this out and focus on th "complicated" parts):

  ```
  $cmd = "montage";
   foreach($images as $image){
     $cmd .= " ".$image.".png";
   }
   $cmd .= " temp.png";
  ```
- now you can execute your command using [exec](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.exec.php) or one of his [friends](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.system.php):

  ```
  exec($cmd);
  ```
- at least, set a png-[header](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.header.php) and use [readfile](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.readfile.php) or something similar to get you "tmp.png"

Comment: i have problem that how to get json data in php web service. i use json_decode($_POST[...]) but it gives error as call to undefined function

Comment: @SumedhTambat: plaese take a look at the dicumentation: the requirements for using json_decode are PHP 5 >= 5.2.0 and PECL json >= 1.2.0 - sound like at least one of these doesn't match.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to [oezi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/288773/oezi) for providing all the pieces.
Here's the complete PHP program:

```
<?php
$nums = json_decode($_REQUEST['nums']);

# Lambda functions are a little less ridiculous in php 5.3 but this is the best
# way I know how to do this in php 5.2:
function f($x) { return "$x.png"; }
$cmd = "montage " . implode(" ", array_map("f", $nums)) . " tmp.png";

exec($cmd);

header('Content-type: image/png');
readfile('tmp.png');
?>
```

Try it out like so:

```
http://yootles.com/nmontage/go.php?nums=[2,4,6]
```

You should get this:

[image: 246]
<sub>(source: [yootles.com](http://yootles.com/nmontage/246.png))</sub>

(That's GET instead of POST of course, but the php program accepts either.)

Comment: +1 nice use of array_map - i thougt about something similar too, but thought it would be too much "overhead" for such a small thing. it's not, like your code proves.