# Webservice that returns an image plus a number

Tags: web-services

If I have a webservice that returns an image, is there a standard way to also have it return some structured data (in the simplest case, an additional string or number)?

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3939980/php-webservice-that-takes-json-via-post-and-spits-back-an-image) for a PHP example of a webservice that returns an image.
(But my question now is not specific to PHP.)

Possible solutions (mostly not very satisfying):

1. Put the extra data in the metadata of the image.
2. Put the extra data in the HTTP headers.
3. Have the webservice return a nonce URL from which the image can be fetched for a limited amount of time.
4. Base64-encode the image and make it huge string field in a JSON or XML data structure. (Thanks to [Carles](https://stackoverflow.com/users/166761/carles-barrobes) and [Tiago](https://stackoverflow.com/users/194855/tiago-deliberali-santos).)

How would you do it?

(I don't really want to just split the webservice into two separate calls because the webservice takes a ton of parameters and it seems wasteful to send them all twice.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTTP headers are a viable choice as they can be parsed easily server side and client side.  Another thing you can do is setup a 302 that redirects it to a URL with the image and data in the URL (e.g ->

1. hit http://mysite.com/bestimageever.png
2. get 302 to http://mysite.com/realbestimage.png?supercoolinfo=42

That'd be transparent to the user and most API clients will work (since they handle redirects)

Comment: Thanks David!  Using the HTTP headers seems a little ... nonstandard, but maybe I'll go with that.  I'm not sure I like the 302 redirect idea since the original URL needs its own parameters to generate the image so it ends up seeming rather messy.

Comment: +1 I like this approach! It implies 2 requests anyway, it's good if the overhead of the base64 encoding is too large

Answer (score 2):

Return the image's binary data encoded in base64, and the additional field:

```
{ image: "mIIerhdkwje...", data: "data" }
```

Base64 encoding gives you an overhead of 33% (you need 4 bytes for each 3 original bytes). Depending on the size of your data it may be better to replace this with the url of the binary data and issue a second request...

Comment: Cool, thanks. I guess this is what Tiago meant in his answer as well.  So you're pretty sure this is the best way to do it?

Comment: It's the one I would use, for lack of knowing better ;)

Answer (score 1):

Protocol buffers are another choice. Protocol buffers aren't self-describing like XML or JSON, but they are much more compact on the wire. The Google library (http://code.google.com/p/protobuf) provides C++, Java, and Python libraries, and contributors have provided libraries for a lot of other languages (http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/wiki/ThirdPartyAddOns), including Javascript and PHP, so client writers should have an easy time working with the format.

Answer (score 0):

isn't it possible to include the binary data to form the image inside the return json/xml? By this way, you could add as many fields as necessary and you could process this information in the client.

Comment: Are you sure that's possible?  Isn't JSON, for example, text only?  I suppose I could encode the image as a huge string and then it could be one of the fields in a JSON object.  Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes. You just need to check your server restrictions to the size of the output generated by the web server. I understood that your application will handle the output of the web server to transform it in a image, for example.